# Flutter http request works on emulator, but not on real android

Tags: flutter, http

The method http.post **works on the emulator**, but when I run this on real android phone it doesn't work.

**Android permission already added.**

Main  AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.niceapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>..
    ...
    ...
```

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: Make sure that the permission is in the main manifest (release one).

Comment: @Tirth Patel yes, it is the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be because you are using localhost. check your url and the network you are in.

Comment: This is Wi-Fi. URL : [http://10.0.2.2:8888].    I've checked it several times already.  Only works with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines:

```
<application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       ...
```

---

This part is optional:

create new folder in res as Android Resource Directory and resource type as xml from dropdown.

add new xml resource file named as "network_security_config"

put this line inside "network_security_config.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your url</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Happy coding :D

Comment: Doesn't work... It is right? Screen : https://yadi.sk/i/Fd3rv4TVbEHlvw

Comment: replace the URL on the 4th line with your URL that you're trying to communicate. If still not working, then, create a new emulator.